# How to assign output of the command to a variable and use that variable in bash?

Tags: bash

$size command is being executed properly but it's not working when used in the until loop condition, I'm unable to understand why it's occuring. Can someone help me with this? TIA.

The error is

```
./Test1.sh: 6: [: Illegal number: jq
```

The code is ::

```
size='jq '.Dependencies\|length' ../Packages.json'
$size
i=0
until [ $i -gt  $size ]
do
  echo i: $i
  i=$((i+1))
done
```

Comment: You prabably want `size=$(jq '.Dependencies|length' ../Packages.json)`, and delete the `$size` line.

Comment: Another tip is that you can replace `i=$((i+1))` with simply `((i++))` or even `((i+=1))`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making a string of code and evaluating it, use [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html).

```sh
size=$(jq '.Dependencies|length' ../Packages.json)

for ((i=0; i<=size; i++)); do
  echo i: $i
done
```

Comment: And an alternative is the C style `for` loop: `for ((i=0; i<=size; i++)); do echo i: $i; done`.

Comment: depending on which shell you're using that `{0..$size}` will fail in bash but will work on zsh and ksh. Well not totally fail but will output a literal `{0..` and what ever the value of `$size` plus a closing `}`. Because brace expansion happens before variable expand at least in bash.